# Apache failing for MediaWiki

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, mediawiki

I have made a mistake while editing config files (new kid on the block). But now our Mediawiki is not being displayed anymore correctly. The page will load but it will display akward, and the normal formatting is gone.

- The page it self is white and missing all kinds of formatting
- Hyperlinks are being displayed in blue, which have not been clicked
- Other hyperlinks that have been clicked are being displayed in purple
- Titles are being displayed in black color

I assume the error is within 000-default.conf. I tried to find the error and correct it my self but I have come to a point whereby I really require assistance. So I was hoping someone could take a look at the config and find what is faulty.

Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

```
Header always unset "X-Powered-By"
Header always unset "Server"
Header unset Server
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Full
#xSecServerSignature Undisclosed
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin"
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set Feature-Policy "fullscreen *"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerName wiki.example.com
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://wiki.example.com"

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mediawiki/"
    <Directory "/var/www/mediawiki/">
            Options +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /mediawiki/
            RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
            RewriteRule ^load\.php$ - [S=1]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . index.php [L]
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    #LogLevel Debug

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH !RC4"
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
#SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName wiki.example.com"
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mediawiki/"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/certs/server.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/certs/server.key"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    <Directory "/var/www/mediawiki/">
            Options +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
            RewriteRule ^load\.php$ - [S=1]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . index.php [L]
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/mediawiki/cache">
            Deny from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/mediawiki/images">
           Deny from all
    </Directory>

    # Protect against bug T30235
    <IfModule rewrite_module>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteOptions inherit
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.[^\\/:*?\x22<>|%]+(#|\?|$) [nocase]
            RewriteRule . - [forbidden]
            # Fix for bug T64289
            Options +FollowSymLinks
    </IfModule>

    <Directory "/var/www/mediawiki/includes">
            Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/mediawiki/languages">
            Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/mediawiki/maintenance">
            Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/mediawiki/mainwiki/maintenance/archives">
            Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/mediawiki/mainwiki/serialized">
            Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/mediawiki/mainwiki/tests">
            Deny from all
    </Directory>

#LogLevel Debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
#prevent https rewrite for parsoid server
<VirtualHost localhost:8142>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: try: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Errors_and_symptoms#The_wiki_appears_without_styles_applied_and_images_are_missing

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` is the culprit. It processes `load.php`, which loads all CSS and JavaScript, breaking it.

You can press F12 in Firefox, choose "Network" tab and follow one of the `load.php` links in the list of loaded files. See what happens. Most probably, it gets redirected into wiki pages.